# Service Control Manager (sc.exe) fails when using a localhost alias in hosts file, but succeeds when using the loopback address directly

Tags: windows, windows-services, hosts, sc.exe

I am running the command:

```
sc \\My-Server create TestService binPath= "C:\Test\Test.exe"
```

However, it fails with

```
[SC] OpenSCManager FAILED 5:

Access is denied.
```

My hosts file contains:

```
127.0.0.1 My-Server
```

However, if I do the command below, it works just fine!

```
sc \\127.0.0.1 create TestService binPath= "C:\Test\Test.exe"
[SC] CreateService SUCCESS
```

I am running cmd as admin. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. I found this thread: https://serverfault.com/questions/184098/why-cant-i-access-an-administrative-share-on-my-local-machine

Step 2: "Allowing server machine to use filesharing with itself via the DNS Alias (BackConnectionHostNames)" is what fixed it for me. I added a multi-string value called `BackConnectionHostNames` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\MSV1_0` and gave it a value of `My-Server`. Ran the `sc` command again, and it worked.